# align = "center" is not working with table

Tags: html, html-table

I have this table I want to align in the middle of the webpage.  But it is stuck on the left hand side of the page.  This is my code:

```
<table class="tableOne" align="center">
    <tr >
        <img src='Images/Header.png' />
    </tr>
</table>
```

What is wrong with the code? I just need the table in the middle of the page.

Comment: 'what is wrong with the code?' Quite a lot for such a small snippet. No table cell, align attribute, no alt text, bad class name usage, and it shouldn't even be a table if it only has one image inside...

Comment: That shouldn't be a table anyway.

Comment: What is your DOCTYPE? HTML5 does not support the `align` attribute.

Answer (score 12):

Don't use `align="center"` it's not a standard property. You could opt use CSS instead.

To center the ***table*** within its container using `margin:auto`.

```
<style>
  .tableOne {
    margin:auto;
  }
</style>
```

To center the ***text within the table cell***, use `text-align:center`.

```
<style>
  .tableOne td {
    text-align:center;
  }
</style>
```

Also you didn't add a `<td>` inside the `<tr>`. You should always make sure the contents of a table cell is within a `<td>` so your HTML is valid.

```
<table class="tableOne">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src='Images/Header.png' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

As a side note, if you're only using the table to center your image you should get rid of the table. This could be replaced by a simple div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="center-me">
    <img src='Images/Header.png' />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.center-me {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Actually I think the missing td did cause the problem. It causes the contents to be placed outside the table. The align property is deprecated but browsers should still understand it.

Comment: @Juhana ah yea, I think you're right. It depends how you would want to center it though. Using `text-align` or `align` would center the *text* within the cell, using `margin:auto` would center the *table* within the container.

Answer (score -2):

As @Juhana writes in a comment, the cause of the problem is lack of `<td>` markup. You need to write

```
<table class="tableOne" align="center">
    <tr >
        <td><img src='Images/Header.png' />
    </tr>
</table>
```

A `tr` may have only `th` and `td` elements as children. This is not just a formal requirement. Browsers *parse* HTML so that if you try to have any other childen there (i.e., any content not placed inside a `th` or `td`), it will be processed as if it preceded the table. (You can see this using Developer Tools, F12, in a browser and inspect the document tree.)

If you just want to center an image, there are simpler ways than a one-cell table, e.g. just `<center><img ...></center>` as well as more elegant ways, like `<img ... class=figure>`in HTML with `.figure { text-align: center }` in CSS

Comment: `<center>` was deprecated in HTML 4.01 as it is describing presentation, not contents.

Comment: The question was not what is deprecated in this or that document or whether something is describing presentation (the intent was clearly to affect presentation), but why the code does not work.

Comment: It was deprecated a *very* long time ago and therefore support could be dropped soon. You shouldn't be suggesting to use something that the web has been trying to get rid of.

Comment: @DanielImms, if you check the HTML5 documents, you will see that HTML5 requires continued support to `center`, and it would be pointless for browsers to drop support. This, on the other hand, has nothing to do with the question that was asked and the simple answer that missing `<td>` is what caused the `align="center"` to fail.